# Set an environmental variable with the date on year in the future

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-dos

I can run this command on my Mac:

```
exp=$(date -v+8760H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

I then run: echo $exp and it produces the desired result i.e. `2021-04-20T09:06:44Z`

I then modified the command to run it on a Linux box:

```
exp=$(date -d '+8760 hour' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

I also need to run this command on a Windows 10 box.  What is the command for Windows? I have managed it on Linux and Mac, but not Windows.

Comment: You probably have your reasons for doing this, but not knowing them may hinder our helping you. I know what curiosity did to the proverbial cat, but this is beyond cryptic IMO... :-)

Comment: Here is a starting point for you [Date Math - Add or subtract days - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-datemath.html)